# Different Session ID in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, sessionid

I have two users in `mysql` database, when one user is logged in, it gets a `session id`. But when 1st user logs out & 2nd user logs in it gets the same `session id` as of the 1st user. I want that even if the browser is not closed, but there are multiple login & logouts from the same browser, the `session id` should change for every user who logs in.

i use the following code :

```
 session_unset();
 session_destroy();
```

Comment: problem solved  <br>

    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array(); // Unset all of the session variables.

    // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
    // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) 
     {
      $params = session_get_cookie_params();
      setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
      $params["path"], $params["domain"],
      $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
     );
    }
    session_destroy();
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Call `session_destroy()` in your logout script.

You can also call it in the login script, if a new user logs in without the old user logging out.

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> **session_destroy()** destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables
>   again, **session_start()** has to be called.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. **setcookie()** may be used for that.

Comment: i use the following code
session_unset();
session_destroy();
still the seesion cookie is not destroyed

Comment: Don't try to post code in comments, click the Edit link under your question.

Comment: See the documentation I pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to explicitly [`destroy`](http://php.net/session_destroy) the session or [regenerate the id](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id).
I'm guessing you're currently just leaving it hanging there.

Answer (score 0):

use `session_destroy()` on your log-out button.

Comment: He said it's happening when the browser is _not_ closed.